# Chaining Dart/Flutter functions each in new line with auto-formatting

Tags: flutter, dart

The auto-formatting in Dart is making a mess in my code, for example this:

```
final list = Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3]);
list
  .map((a) => a * 2)
  .map((b) => b * 3)
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

becomes this:

```
final list = Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3]);
list.map((a) => a * 2).map((b) => b * 3).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Is there a way to preserve the line breaks during auto-formatting in places where I use the dot character to chain functions? By auto-formatting I mean pressing CTRL+ALT+L in Android Studio.

Comment: Using Format Document in Visual Studio code or Reformat code with dartfmt in android studio produces the desired result. What command are you using to format your code that produces the wrong output ?

Comment: By auto-formatting I mean pressing CTRL+ALT+L in Android Studio.

Comment: @Muldec I updated the snippet with shorter names, so it should happen to you even with the 80-character line limit.

Comment: Ok, I see it now.

Comment: If I understand them correctly, cascades are just multiple operations on the same object, they are not chaining the return value of the cascade above them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a little bit hacky, but you can use comments (even empty one) to preserve line breaks:

```dart
void main() {
  final list = Stream.fromIterable([1, 2, 3]);
  list //
      .map((a) => a * 2)
      .map((b) => b * 3)
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

Comment: It does indeed help... But I'm going to wait a little while before accepting this answer to give someone a chance to present a less hacky one :)

Comment: Did you find a proper solution?

Comment: This negates the main point of a formatter: to have consistent formatting without manual developer intervention because this puts the onus on the developer to remember to add the comment.